# Logging the Connection String used to access SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection

Is there any way of logging the connection string used to access a SQL database?. We have a C# application which has many places where the application opens a connection to SQL, performs a query and then closes the connection. At some point it is using the wrong connection string without the port number to connect to the appropriate SQL instance but seems to continue to work but responses are very slow.

I have several links to audit which users are logged on etc but none of them record the connection string used. Is there something like an inbuilt SQL query I can use to find this information?

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms is used?

Comment: Are you using the Microsoft Logging Facade? And what kind of App is it?

Comment: SQL Server has a default port number and it you are using the default the port is not needed.  The speed is determined by the speed of the machine SQL is running (and number of cores), the amount of memory on the machine, the size of the database, the amount of data being returned, and the driver being used.  SQL Server is meant to be installed on the fastest machine, lots of cores, and lots of memory.  If you run a large database on a regular machine it is going to be slow.  Using a different driver can help.  See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to log the answer within your application then sql won't be able to help you here, I would suggest you create a wrapper method around your sql call.  the exact code will vary according to the library you use but in c# esc pseudocode it would look something like

```
private string RunSql(parameters)
{
    myLogger.log($"my connection string is {connectionString}");
    connection.Execute(parameters);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I did something along those lines and found the problem!

Comment: @NigelTunnicliffe if this has answered your question, could you consider tagging it as the accepted answer?